# Always get related model of relationship model in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have three Eloquent Models:

`Company`, `OrdersArea` and `Localization` where a company has many orders areas and orders area always have one localization.

I need to getting the Orders Area model to always load with Localization

If I do that:

```
$company = auth()->user()->company;
```

I gets Company of logged user without OrdersArea and it's ok.

and next I could do:

```
$company->ordersArea;
```

and then I have in $company related models - OrdersArea - but this models doesn't have Localization in itself but I need to get this always.

And in this situation:

```
$ordersArea = OrdersArea::find($id);
```

I want to get also $odersArea with localization property ($ordersArea->localization) with model.

How to do that - loading/getting $ordersArea always with related localization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the Localization with the `ordersArea()` relation, you can use Eager loading. You can read more about this in the documentation: [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

**Example**

```
$company->ordersArea()
    ->with('localization')
    ->first();
```

[Alternatively](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default), you can add the `protected $with = ['localization'];` to your `OrdersArea` model. This will **always** load the localization with the `OrdersArea`. You should only use this if that relation is **always** required.

You can also retrieve the relation after the parent model has already been retrieved. This is called [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

```
$ordersArea = OrdersArea::find($id);
$ordersArea->load('localization');
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very useful. I use load for Company, and with property in OrdersArea and it's what I want Company have areas which each have localization. But I wonder how to that without `with` property inside OrdersArea class. I mean it's possible to do that only with load methods? Something like this: $company->load(['ordersAreas', 'localization'], but localization must be related with ordersAreas not company obviously.

Comment: Yes, you can use load for [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading). So something like this: `$company->load('ordersArea.localization');` using the `dot` notation. This should load the Company, with the related OrderAreas, and the OrderAreas contain the Localization model.

Comment: Brilliant, it was very informative. Thank you so much, again. 
It's a pity you have to use literals (I don't like magic strings/numbers), but it's okey, - this not a problem - could by solved by const. :)

Comment: Yes, using literals is slightly unfortunate. The names of the relationships almost never change though, so it should be fine. Using a `const` can solve this indeed. If you use the load in several places,  you could consider refactoring the `->load('ordersArea.localization');` to a function in `Company` model, for example `loadOrderAreasLocalization()`. And then you can call `$company->loadOrderAreasLocalization()`. If the literals change, you only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Use this inside `OrdersArea` model -

```
protected $with = ['localization'];
```

It will always load `localization` whenever you query `OrdersArea`.